# How to import 3500+ Woocommerce products throughout the day to sync a POS database

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am an experienced C# programmer working in WordPress and PHP. I'm working with a team to build a Woocommerce integration to an external point of sale API.

The API call is pulling JSON of 3,500 products (sku, attributes, desc, price, taxes, etc.). The WordPress programmers have set this up as a cron job that deletes all relevant WordPress data and repopulate it one-by-one using WordPress calls through a loop of all products, taxonomies, etc.

The biggest problem is that the page only makes it through about 250 items per 5 minute timeout so it doesn't work.  And, we need a solution that can run hourly to keep the Woocommerce site as synced up as possible to the POS system.

I suggested the Woocommerce API but was told that it has an item limit and is still not solving this issue.  I'm having a hard time finding a solution through days of searching.

The full code is long, so here is pseudo-code:

```
Delete all related info from:
    wp_terms
    wp_term_taxonomy
    wp_term_relationships
    wp_postmeta
    wp_postmeta
    wp_posts
    wp_termmeta

For each product in 3,500 json products {

    // build set of 35 attribute variables.. example:
    if( !empty($product->on_hand) ){ $on_hand = number_format($product->on_hand, 0); } else { $on_hand = 0; }
    ... x35

    // create/update 12 taxonomies... example:
    if(!empty($is_staff_picks)){
        $term_is_staff_picks = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Staff Picks', 'pa_special_requirements', true );
        $product_attributes_data['pa_special_requirements'] = Array( 'name' => 'pa_special_requirements', 'value' => 'Staff Picks', 'is_visible' => '1', 'is_variation' => '0', 'is_taxonomy' => '1' );
    }
    ... x12

    // add attributes that aren't taxonomies.. example:
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_product_attributes',$product_attributes_data);

    // create the simple product type.. example:
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );

    // make 32 function calls to update/add metadata.. example:
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', $val );
    ... x32
}
... x3,500
```

Comment: If they do it with Ajax, and loop through it for each product, then it won't timeout

Comment: but that probably won't work with cron... hmm

Comment: Thanks @Stender It seems to be a tough one... I've spent days searching for a clean solution with success.  The developers are also searching for a solution - we can't be the only ones that have come across this issue with all of the woocommerce databases out there.

Comment: But if you want to call the function every hours - with all 3500 products, and it does 250 products in 5 minutes, it will take you 70 minutes to finish your function - which also means, that you will try to call it, when it is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote most of this functionality.

Now, each POS item has a single meta_value saved with it that is used as a comparison value (built from the parts of the description that may change).

Every 30 minutes, we run a cron job that pulls all items and uses this one field to compare, to check for changes.  We `unset` items that are the same.
If the item has changed, we put it into an "update" array.  If it is new we put it in a "to be added" array and anything left over has been removed, so we keep the remnants of the array there as a "remove" array.

Then, each array is gone through to add/update/remove the items from the database.  The whole process now only takes a few minutes even though the item count has almost doubled.

For inventory counts, we do something similar but we just look at the on-hand inventory count associated with each item (nothing else).  We are limited to 5 minute updates, so we run this every 5 minutes to keep the inventory as accurate as possible.